# Suggest Password in Safari when Changing Password

Tags: ios, keychain, mobile-safari

When signing up for a new website in iOS, Safari (or keychain, whoever) will offer to suggest a new password and save it in iCloud. But, when you need to change or update a password, Safari does not offer this functionality. Is there a way to ask Safari to generate a new password for you even if there is already a password stored in the keychain?